# How to sort in-text citations by year, but bibliography by name?

Tags: bibliographies, biber, sorting

I am writing a document using the `memoir` class, pdflatex and biber. Now both my Bibliography at the end of the document and the citations in the text sort alphabetically, but I would like the citations to sort by year. How can i achieve this?

In my preamble I have this:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}%
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

and I have made a config file that looks like this:

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{dashed=false, block=space, firstinits, maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=99, sortcites, sorting=nyt, uniquelist=false}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{
\printfield{volume}
\setunit*{\addnbthinspace}
\printfield{number}
\setunit{\addcomma\space}
\printfield{eid}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
```

As far as I understand the sorting option does half the trick as it changes both bib and cite order. Suggestions?

Comment: What exactly is your question? `sorting=nyt, sortcites` are exactly the right options if you want your bibliography sorted by name and then year, and have the citations sorted accordingly. You can use `sorting=ynt` to sort by year, name and title (in that order). Do you want *only* the citations to be sorted by year and not the bibliography? In that case specify the citation sorting in `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions` (e.g. `sorting=nyt`) and use the optional argument to `\printbibliography` to declare sorting in the bibliography: `\printbibliography[sorting=nty]`.

Comment: I was asking for, as you guessed, how to sort the printed bibliography by name, and the in-text citations by year. By '\ExecuteBibliographyOptions' and add 'sorting=ynt' (in the config file), and write '\printbibliography[soring=nyt]' this was solved. Thank you very much!

Comment: @moewe Didn't work for me :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is an answer for a now very outdated version of `biblatex`. For more recent versions please refer to [Biblatex: how to automatically sort citation by year (sortcites=ynt) when references are sorted by name (sorting=nyt)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/361031/35864).

`biblatex`'s `sorting` option can be applied globally (that is in the package loading options, or via `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions`). The global sorting scheme is then used to sort citations - if `sortcites` is used - , it is furthermore employed to sort all bibliographies and lists of shorthands printed via `\printbibliography` or `\printshorthands`.

If you want to sort a bibliography using a different sorting scheme than the global one, you can specify that sorting scheme in the optional argument to `\printbibliography`: `\printbibliography[sorting=nty]`.

In your case, you would probably want the global sorting scheme `sorting=ynt`, so load `biblatex` with `\usepackage[sorting=ynt]{biblatex}`, or `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{sorting=ynt}`. Your bibliography sorting scheme would be `sorting=nty`, so you print your bibliography via `\printbibliography[sorting=nty]`.

Comment: I didn't works for me. Do you know why?

Comment: @DanielValencia In newer versions of `biblatex` you cannot pass the `sorting` option to `\printbibliography` any more, you will have to use refcontexts. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/244971/35864. This can mess up the disambiguation labels, so I cannot recommend doing it (see also the warning in the manual about that).

Comment: @moewe: Do you refer to section 3.7.10 "Reference Contexts"?

Comment: @gerw I do indeed.