# Different sorting schemes in text and bibliography

Tags: biblatex, sorting

Using biblatex with bibtex, I would like to order my references in the bibliography by author name.

This works fine:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, sorting = nyt, %name, year, title]{biblatex}
```

However this behaviour also applies to citations in the text, when quoting several authors. for instance:

```
\parencite{Wang_1976, Albert_2011}
```

gives

> (Albert et al. 2011, Wang et al. 1976)

Where I would like the citation to appear in chronological order. Changing `sorting` to `ynt`, solves this issue, but disrupts the ordering in the bibliography instead. I can't get my head around it...

Obs: I use sharelatex.

Comment: Please see [Biblatex order of entries in a multi-citation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/244971/35864).

Comment: In case that helped you a short heads up would be nice. If the solution did not help, please explain why. If nothing happens here in due time the question will probably be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @moewe, the link you posted seemed highly relevant, that is why I upvoted it. Nevertheless I have not have time to test the proposed solution, this is why I did not answer your comment. Sorry for this! It is not otherwise my habit to leave answers/comment unresponded.

Comment: I hope I didn't come across as to rude, sorry. The problem with up-voting is that one doesn't know who up-voted, so I wasn't aware you had read the comment and the linked question.

Comment: @moewe, thanks for the link. I think this is indeed a duplicate, as I am trying to do the same thing as the other OP. Yet, I would not have thought of formulated the problem the way he did, and could not find it despite many searches.
The proposed solution did not work for me, probably because I use `backend=bibtex` and I opted for sorting the citations manually with `sortcites=false`. Any more elegant solution is much welcome...

Comment: Now I'm confused. If you have `sortcites=false` how does any sorting option change the order of citations? If you have `sortcites=false` that means precisely that `biblatex` will just print citations in the order you gave them. Why don't you just go with the bibliography order you want. As I really don't understand your problem a full MWE and a precise description what output you expect might help.

Comment: I am sorry that I have confused you. I meant I sorted the citations "manually" in the order I wanted in each `\parencite{}` environment. In addition of that I had to turn off `sortcites` to keep this manual order unchanged. So no, there are no sorting options on the top of that; and yes, problem solved, except that I do not find the solution very elegant.

Comment: Never mind. Can you explain in more detail how and why the proposed solution did not work for you? Does it work in the MWE in the answer? (Manually sorting is indeed not very elegant, but the solution in the MWE seems nice.)