# Different ordering scheme for multiple citations and for bibliography in Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, sorting

UPDATE (10/09/16): the problem reported here is due to a bug in biber 2.6.

I want to have multiple citations in `textcite` in the text with a different ordering scheme than in the bibliography. I am using `biblatex 3.6` with `biber 2.6` In [moewe's previous answer a year ago](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247188/74706) it was suggested to use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,sorting=ydnt,sortcites]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite{worman,geer,baez/article,wilde,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}

\begin{refcontext}[sorting=ynt]
\printbibliography
\end{refcontext}
\end{document}
```

But when using this, I don't get the descending ordering he posted, but rather

> Knuth (1984), Knuth (1986), Wilde (1899), Geer (1985), Worman (2002),
>   and Baez and Lauda (2004)

What is particularly strange is that the ordering of the `textcite` and of the biblography are identical. This sorting is very strange, because it is ascending except for the

> Wilde (1899)

outlier. I guess there has been a change to `biblatex` so that a new solution is needed (or there is a bug).

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I get the expected order in both citations and bibliography. I'm using 3.4/2.5, though.

Comment: I'm assuming this is a bug. Have you checked if it is a known one?

Comment: Actually, you don't need an example this complicated. Just set sorting to `ynt` and comment out the `refcontext` to see the problem.

Comment: https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/144

Comment: You can either wait for an update to fix this or you can download Biblatex 3.7 and Biber 2.7 from SourceForge. [Source: see response to my bug report above.]

Comment: Thanks for reporting this to the `biber` team and the quick reply.

Comment: I'm also having similar problems with two different sorting patterns conflicting. I have section bibliographies with a numeric scheme, set up with `refsegment=section` and then a global bibliography printed sorted `nyt` in authoryear style. With biblatex v3.6 and biber v2.6 the citations are numbered according to their order in the global bibliography, rather than order of appearance.

The new versions of biblatex 3.7 and biber 2.7 don't fix it. I get the old behavior back if I roll back to biblatex 3.4 and biber 2.5. Examples at [issue](https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/144) on github.

Comment: Looking at it. It is amusing that people refer to me as a "team"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is due to two small bugs in Biber that have been fixed in the development version 2.8 (https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/144).

The MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,sorting=ydnt,sortcites]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite{worman,geer,baez/article,wilde,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}

\begin{refcontext}[sorting=ynt]
\printbibliography
\end{refcontext}
\end{document}
```

now produces

[image: Baez and Lauda (2004), Worman (2002), Knuth (1986), Geer (1985), Knuth (1984), and Wilde (1899)]

as expected.