# Sort citations according to year, while being "grouped" by authors

Tags: biblatex, sorting

I'm trying to make my bibliography list and in-text citations to mimic the style used by the institution where I study, and I've run into an issue regarding sorting of in-text citations. I am greatful for any help I can get.

The in-text citation should have chronological sorting, however with works by the same author(s) "grouped" by name/author. The bibliography list should be sorted as "nyt". I've put together an example below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[swedish,french,english]{babel} 

\usepackage[]{xpatch}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber,dashed=false,dateabbrev=false,doi=true,firstinits=true,isbn=false,maxbibnames=8,minbibnames=8,maxcitenames=2,sortcites=true,sorting=ynt,url=false,urldate=comp,uniquename=false,uniquelist=false,useprefix=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage[]{csquotes}
\usepackage[]{doi}
\usepackage{hyperref}\urlstyle{same}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=false
    ,pdfborder={0 0 0}
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{van_wagner_conditions_1977,
  title = {Conditions for the start and spread of crown fire},
  volume = {7},
  journaltitle = {Canadian Journal of Forest Research},
  author = {van Wagner, C. E.},
  date = {1977},
  pages = {23--34}
}
@report{albini_estimating_1976,
  location = {{Ogden, UT, USA}},
  title = {Estimating {{Wildfire Behavior}} and {{Effects}}},
  number = {INT-30},
  institution = {{USDA Forest Service, Intermountain Forest and Range Experiment Station}},
  type = {General {{Technical Report}}},
  author = {Albini, Frank A.},
  date = {1976-01-01},
  pages = {92}
}
@article{richards_mathematical_1999,
  title = {The mathematical modelling and computer simulation of wildland fire perimeter growth over a 3-dimensional surface},
  volume = {9},
  number = {3},
  journaltitle = {International Journal of Wildland Fire},
  author = {Richards, Gwynfor D.},
  date = {1999-01-01},
  pages = {213--221}
}
@article{richards_elliptical_1990,
  title = {An elliptical growth model of forest fire fronts and its numerical solution},
  volume = {30},
  number = {6},
  journaltitle = {International Journal for Numerical Methods in Engineering},
  author = {Richards, Gwynfor D.},
  date = {1990-10-20}
}
@article{richards_properties_1993,
  title = {The {{Properties}} of {{Elliptical Wildfire Growth}} for {{Time Dependent Fuel}} and {{Meteorological Conditions}}},
  volume = {95},
  number = {1-6},
  author = {Richards, Gwynfor D.},
  date = {1993-12-01},
  pages = {357--383}
}
@article{richards_general_1995,
  title = {A {{General Mathematical Framework}} for {{Modeling Two-Dimensional Wildland Fire Spread}}},
  volume = {5},
  number = {2},
  journaltitle = {International Journal of Wildland Fire},
  author = {Richards, Gwynfor D.},
  date = {1995-01-01},
  pages = {63--72}
}
@inproceedings{finney_modeling_1994,
  location = {{Bethesda, MD, USA}},
  title = {Modeling the spread and behavior of prescribed natural fires},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the 12th {{International Conference}} on {{Fire}} and {{Forest Meteorology}}},
  publisher = {{Society of American Foresters}},
  author = {Finney, M. A.},
  date = {1994},
  pages = {138--143}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\noindent\textcite{van_wagner_conditions_1977,richards_mathematical_1999,richards_elliptical_1990,finney_modeling_1994,richards_properties_1993,richards_general_1995,albini_estimating_1976}

\vspace{1cm}\noindent\parencite{van_wagner_conditions_1977,richards_mathematical_1999,richards_elliptical_1990,finney_modeling_1994,richards_properties_1993,richards_general_1995,albini_estimating_1976}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I used `soting=ynt` above since that would give me chronological sorting but it doesn't group citations the way I want them to. I've been playing around with sorting schemes but I can't manage to get it working.

When using `\textcite`, the above code prints out:

> Albini (1976), van Wagner (1977), Richards (1990, 1993), Finney (1994), Richards (1995, 1999)

and when using `\parencite`:

> (Albini 1976; van Wagner 1977; Richards 1990, 1993; Finney 1994; Richards 1995, 1999)

Though, I wish to get the following when using `\textcite`:

> Albini (1976), van Wagner (1977), Richards (1990, 1993, 1995, 1999), and Finney (1994)

and this when using `\parencite`:

> (Albini 1976; van Wagner 1977; Richards 1990, 1993, 1995, 1999; Finney 1994)

I guess it is related to `\DeclateSortingScheme{}` which I don't understand yet.

(I aim to use `refcontext` as seen in the following snipped instead of `\printbibliography`, but for some reason it changes the sorting of the citations to `nyt`. I don't know why but it might relate to a bug that was around in biber v2.6 as stated here: [Different ordering scheme for multiple citations and for bibliography in Biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332978/different-ordering-scheme-for-multiple-citations-and-for-bibliography-in-biblate). Maybe the bug is still around in biber v2.7?)

```
\begin{refcontext}[sorting=nyt]
    \begingroup
        \raggedleft
        \sloppy
        \printbibliography
    \endgroup
\end{refcontext}
```

I am using biblatex v3.7 and biber v2.7.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you want the bibliography to look like? Further, why on the in text citations (`\textcite` and `\parencite`) is it Albini, van Wagner, Richards, Finney. Wouldn't it be Albini, Finny, Richards, van Wagner?

Comment: @StrongBad The bibliography should be sorted by first name `sorting=nyt`. I'll edit and add that to my post shortly. No, that's the sort order when using `sorting=nyt`. I want them sorted according to year/date, but with works by the same order grouped together. (Not logical at all but that's the way the Journal wants it sorted). I'll edit my post to print out an example of the sorting of the bibliography.

Comment: Are you sure? The one [article](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s13280-016-0809-2/fulltext.html) I looked at sorted in text citations chronologically with no grouping: `McMichael 1999; Daszak et al. 2001; McMichael 2004; Daszak 2005; Castillo-Chavez et al. 2015` (notice the two McMichael entries). The [instructions for authors](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/Instructions_for_authors_AMBIO_2016.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-960937-p173951212) says chronological order and nothing about grouping.

Comment: @StrongBad Interesting. No I am not 100% sure but I've seen that sorting a few times. Fore example in this [article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s13280-016-0795-4). There you find the following: `(Genko 1902–1903; Karcov 1903, Kocan 1957; Więcko 1963, 1984; Faliński 1966, 1986; Jędrzejewska et al. 1997)`. I wasn't sure myself and asked my resource at the Institution where I study and she told me this was the expected sorting. However, she might have miss-interpreted it also. I'll check back with her tomorrow. Chronological seem better.

Comment: @StrongBad I've been talking to the resource at my institution and it turns out that you're correct - the Ambio style says chronologic sorting only. However, my institution wants the citations grouped also as I described it in the question. Any ideas of how to achieve such a sorting scheme?

Comment: Mhh, I don't think this is a bug, there is simply no sorting scheme that does what you want. You can't have `nyt` because you want to give years priority over names, but you can't have `ynt` because you don't want the sorting to be too much by year, since you still want to group all sources per author.

Comment: @moewe, isn't it supposed to work having chronological sorted citations, while having alphabetical sorting in the bibliography? Maybe I missunderstood that from the documentation. I though `refcontext` override the global sorting for the bibliography to allow different sortings. I understand that none of ynt or nyt will sort with grouping and thus that's what I try to achieve but with no success so far. I was hoping it would be possible to come up with a different sorting scheme to achieve that. E.g. having a different sorting for citations while using `nyt` for the bibliography.

Comment: I made the question shorter and hopefully clearer.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to have different sorting schemes in citations and the bibliography, there are a few caveats though. One problem is that it is not entirely impossible - if admittedly unlikely - that a disambiguation letter (the a in 'Smith 2006a') is different in the two sorting schemes, this means that the citation 'Smith 2006b' actually refers to 'Smth 2006a' in the bibliography - a nightmare (see also pp. 88-90 of the `biblatex` documentation).

Comment: ... But as I was saying, I don't believe that within the current framework there will ever be a sorting such as you desire for citations. You would essentially have to be able to back-track through the current list of citations. The sorting schemes currently take a list of fields which they compare 'lexicographically' and - importantly - only once, for your sorting scheme it is imperative that the sorting order be recalculated for every `\cite`. (Because in `\cite{finnley1994,richards1999}` Finnley goes fist, but in `\cite{finnley1994,richards1999,richards1993}` Richards does.)

Comment: @moewe, okay I see your point. That would be a complete disaster if the disambiguation letters are mixed up. Then I guess the only working solution is to sort the bibliography alphabeticaly `sorting=nyt` and set `sortcites=false`. Then put the references in the order I prefer in the text. It's a pitty it doesn't work to have them automatically sorted. I was hoping to find a solution similar to nested conditions `if(){if(){}}`. Maybe it will work in the far future. Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 1):

With how sorting is implemented at the moment there can never be a sorting scheme that gives you what you want.
At the moment you can't do context-dependent sorting. Whenever you compare two entries to determine who goes first you will always obtain the same answer.

You can either sort by `author`/`editor`/... first, or you can sort by `year` first. Both won't give you what you need.

For your citation scheme one would first have list all authors and then all the years for each author. Then sorting would commence by sorting the authors not by their names but by the first year associated with them. It is clear that this sorting scheme is context dependent.

You want

> Richards (1990, 1993, 1995, 1999), and Finney (1994)

But

> Finney (1994), and Richards (1995, 1999)

In the first case Finney1994 sorts after Richards1999, but in the second case before.