# Biblatex: how to automatically sort citation by year (sortcites=ynt) when references are sorted by name (sorting=nyt)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, sorting

I want to sort in-text citations by year, but bibliography by name. It sound exactly like [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/162485/64454).

However, suggested solution (using `\usepackage[sorting=ynt]{biblatex}` and `\printbibliography[sorting=nty]`) does not work for me (see MWEB below). Indeed, the list of references remains year-sorted instead of name sorted.

**Question:** How to force `sorting=nty` in `\printbibliography`?

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[%
        backend=biber,%
        style=authoryear-comp,%
        natbib=true,%
        sorting=ynt%
    ]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
    \usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{key2000,
      author = {Author, A.},
      year = {2000},
      title = {Alphabetical fist \& Year last},
      publisher = {Publisher},
    }
    @book{key1900,
        author = {Boathor, B.},
        year = {1900},
        title = {Alphabetical last \& Year first},
        publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    Citation should be year-sorted, even if \verb+\citep+ is random \citep{key2000, key1900}.% citation NOT year-sorted

    \printbibliography[sorting=nyt]
\end{document}
```

**P.S.:** At the opposite, using

```
\begingroup
    \newrefcontext[sorting=nyt]
    \printbibliography
\endgroup
```

overrides the `\usepackage[sorting=ynt]{biblatex}` option (i.e. LoR is name-sorted, but in-line citations as well).

Comment: At the moment, I'm afraid, it looks quite bleak. I hope someone comes up with a good answer. See [Different citation order in text and bibliography using biblatex and latexmk](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/359227/35864), [Multiple citations: citation order different to bibliography order](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/344807/35864). The problem is that if you use different sorting schemes the disambiguation letters might be off.

Comment: The problem is that the `sorting` option has been moved from `\printbibliography` to so called 'refcontexts'. See [Biblatex order of entries in a multi-citation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/244971/35864). And the default is that all citations obey the refcontext they were last printed in the bibliography. So simply using a global `sorting` that contradicts the `\printbibliography`'s `refcontext`'s `sorting` does not work

Comment: @moewe I indeed saw [Biblatex order of entries in a multi-citation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/314653/64454) and started to use `sortcites=false` and manually sorting references within citation... but I wanted to be lazy and make (Bib)LaTeX do it for me! | Just to be sure to understand your previous comment: the sorting scheme chosen, is the one of the `refcontext` selected *when `printbibliography` is called* and not at the time of the `\cite` command, right? (I tried to add `\newrefcontext[sorting=ynt]` right after `\begin{document}` + what I added in my P.S, but it indeed doesn't work.)

Comment: Indeed. Specifically it is the refcontext of the last appearance of the particularly entry in an `\printbibliography`. There are ways to manually assign the refcontext (i.e. override the 'use the refcontext of the last bibliography' rule). But you need to be careful about potentially different extrayears.

Comment: Did my answer work for you even in your actual production document?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Update

With `biblatex` v3.18 and above you can use `\localrefcontext` and `\GenRefcontextData` to switch to a different reference context (e.g. sorting).

Use

```
\AtBeginRefsection{\GenRefcontextData{sorting=ynt}}
```

to make sure that each `refcontext` our document uses also generates an analogous `refcontext` with `ynt` sorting.

Then

```
\AtEveryCite{\localrefcontext[sorting=ynt]}
```

switches our citations to the `ynt` sorting `refcontext`. `\localrefcontext` only acts locally and need not be "closed" or reset because it happens inside a group.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=authoryear-comp,
  % sortcites=true, % not needed here because it is implied by style=authoryear-comp,
]{biblatex}

\AtBeginRefsection{\GenRefcontextData{sorting=ynt}}
\AtEveryCite{\localrefcontext[sorting=ynt]}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key2000,
  author    = {Author, A.},
  year      = {2000},
  title     = {Alphabetical fist \& Year last},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@book{key1900,
  author    = {Boathor, B.},
  year      = {1900},
  title     = {Alphabetical last \& Year first},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  Lorem \autocite{key2000, key1900}

  ipsum \autocite{key1900, key2000}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Boathor 1900; Author 2000) ipsum (Boathor 1900; Author 2000) References Author, A. (2000). Alphabetical fist & Year last. Publisher. Boathor, B. (1900). Alphabetical last & Year first. Publisher.]

See also [Sort citations by year (ynt) and references by name (nyt) in custom biblatex style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/647866/35864).

---

### Solution for older versions of `biblatex`

Give the desired citation sort order at loading time. Then give the desired order for the bibliography in the new refcontext (`\begin{refcontext}[sorting=<sorting>]...\end{refcontext}`) for `\printbibliography`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=authoryear-comp, sorting=ynt,
  % sortcites=true, % not needed here because it is implied by style=authoryear-comp,
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key2000,
  author    = {Author, A.},
  year      = {2000},
  title     = {Alphabetical fist \& Year last},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@book{key1900,
  author    = {Boathor, B.},
  year      = {1900},
  title     = {Alphabetical last \& Year first},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  Lorem \autocite{key2000, key1900}

  ipsum \autocite{key1900, key2000}

  \begin{refcontext}[sorting=nyt]
  \printbibliography
  \end{refcontext}
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Boathor 1900; Author 2000)//ipsum (Boathor 1900; Author 2000)]

I used

```
\begin{refcontext}[sorting=nyt]
\printbibliography
\end{refcontext}
```

instead of the slightly shorter

```
\newrefcontext[sorting=nyt]
```

to be on the safe side if there are citations *after* the bibliography.

---

### Hints and Caveats

Some more explanation since this comes up more often.

`biblatex` does not allow the `sorting` option for `\printbibliography` any more. It was removed because it could lead to weird sorting results.

Instead, now you use 'refcontexts' to control sorting. A refcontext controls `sorting`, `labelprefix` and `sortingnamekeytemplate` and a few other things (possible more in the future).

An entry can appear in different refcontexts and any extra label data (`extradate`, `extraalpha`) will be recalculated based on the specific details (e.g. sorting) for each refcontext.

This can lead to slightly counter-intuitive results in very contrived examples because the sort order may be determined by data that is invisible in the citation itself and those data leads to different sorting results in different schemes.

Here is an admittedly very artificial example that shows this behaviour with your set-up. It can be much easier to achieve such an effect with other pairings of sort schemes. The trick here was that `nyt` considers the `volume` for sorting while `ynt` does not.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, sorting=ynt, sortcites]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{one,
  author = {Elk, Anne},
  title  = {Title},
  volume = {1},
  note   = {sorts first in ynt},
}
@book{two,
  author = {Elk, Anne},
  title  = {Title},
  note   = {sorts first in nyt},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{one,two} \autocite{two,one}

\begin{refcontext}[sorting=nyt]
\printbibliography[title={\refname{} (sorting \texttt{nyt})}]
\end{refcontext}
\end{document}
```

[image: (Elk n.d.[b]; Elk n.d.[a]) (Elk n.d.[b]; Elk n.d.[a])]

Comment: Can you construct a situation in which the situation described in your last paragraph actually occurs? If I understand it correctly, two entries should only receive an `extrayear`, if they have the same authors and the same year. However, in this case the order is the same, both in `nyt` and `ynt`. Hence, the `extrayear` will not differ.

Comment: @gerw See the edit, please. The example is contrived and uses a dependence on the `volume` field in one of the two schemes that might not have been immediately obvious, but it shows that the problem can be reproduced and is not purely theoretical. As mentioned in the answer, other pairings of schemes might be much more susceptible to these kind of entries.

Comment: I see. However, if I add the (quite reasonable) assumption that no two titles are the same (at least with same authors and years), can something like this happen with `nyt` and `ynt`, too?

Comment: @gerw In that case you are *probably* safe. At least I can't think of an example that would be problematic in that case off the top of my head. I would, however, not rely on things working out smoothly when it is possible to come up with problematic cases. Keep in mind that with other sort schemes different things might trigger the problematic behaviour.

Comment: ... Additionally, this is only one (arguably the most - maybe even the only - visible) symptom of the separation into different `refcontext`s. There are few other things that can differ between `refcontext`s, if that list expands in future versions, this could become more problematic.

Comment: I understand. However, I really like to have `ynt` in the text and `nyt` in the bibliography. Btw, what is the explanation of this weird behaviour with `volume`?

Comment: @gerw Well, if you must really have it, then currently the answer is the only way to go (save for sorting the citations manually yourself). It makes sense to include the `volume` for sorting in many schemes (think a multi-volume work published all in the same year), but in `ynt` it would not be clear where in the sort order `volume` should go, that's why it is omitted (I think, I can't be sure of course). Since a missing volume is equivalent to `volume = {0}` for sorting purposes in all schemes that use `volume` this allows us to generate the problematic case above.

Comment: @moewe, how to use `refcontext` together with `refsection`?

Comment: @bonanza As usual: You can have `\newrefcontext` or `\begin{refcontext}...\end{refcontext}` inside a refsection. Does that not work for you? If you have problems with this, I suggest you ask a new question with an MWE.

Answer (score 7):

A 'quick and dirty' solution (less good than [moewe's one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361042/64454)) is use `biblatex`'s *`sortcites=false`* option, to enable the manual sorting of in-line citations.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[%
        backend=biber,%
        style=authoryear-comp,%
        natbib=true,%
        sorting=nyt,%
        sortcites=false,
    ]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
    \usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{A2000,
      author = {Author, A.},
      year = {2000},
      title = {Alphabetical fist \& Year last},
      publisher = {Publisher},
    }
    @book{B1900,
        author = {Boathor, B.},
        year = {1900},
        title = {Alphabetical last \& Year first},
        publisher = {Publisher},
    }

    @book{C1950,
        author = {Coathor, C.},
        year = {1950},
        title = {Alphabetical last \& Year first},
        publisher = {Publisher},   
    } 
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    In-line citations should be manually sorted in the desired order, and the References list will be alphabetically sorted.

    Example: 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item This citation is manually year-sorted \citep{B1900, C1950, A2000},
        \item this one is manually shuffled \citep{C1950, B1900, A2000}.
    \end{itemize}

    \printbibliography[]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Quick for sure but definitively not dirty (@moewe one is the dirty ones as they explained), so works very well for me (requires ordering the citation yourself of course, so does not totally answer the “even if citep is random” part, but that is much more convenient actually).