# How to change the order in which articles are quoted inside \citet{article1,article2,...}?

Tags: biblatex

At some point in my Thesis I write something like what the following MWE generates.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[isbn=false,style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber,natbib,maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=2,hyperref=true]{biblatex} % To get fancy bibliography as desired.
\usepackage{csquotes} % To make sure that my Bibliography loads correctly.

% REFERENCES SETTINGS

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}

% BIBLIOGRAPHY SETTINGS

\addbibresource{Bib.bib}
\setlength\bibitemsep{2\itemsep}
\AtBeginBibliography{ 
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamesuffix}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-first}
\DeclareDelimFormat[cbx@textcite]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\small}

\begin{document}
Following \citet{hartmascolell,evans}, utilities... 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Call the associated .bib file Bib.bib and save it in the same folder as the MWE for the MWE to run. The .bib file should exactly be:

```
@article{hartmascolell,
author = "S. Hart and A. Mas-Colell",
title = "Bargaining and Value",
journal = "Econometrica",
volume = "64",
pages = "357--380",
year = "1996",
url = "https://doi.org/10.2307/2171787"
}

@article{evans,
author = "R. Evans",
title = "Coalitional Bargaining with Competition to Make Offers",
journal = "Games and Economic Behavior",
volume = "19",
pages = "211--220",
year = "1997",
url = "https://doi.org/10.1006/game.1997.0553"
}
```

Then, we obtain the following output:

[image]

I suspect that Evans appears before Hart & Mas-Colell because the order is lexicographic. However, to me, it would make more sense to get first Hart & Mas-Colell and then Evans because of the time-order of the papers (one is from 1996 and the other one is from 1997).

Therefore, my question is: **how can I change the order in which authors appear from lexicographic to temporal?** And also: **is there any reason for which the lexicographic order is better (aka, default)?**

*Note: unless there is a reason not do so, I want to keep the order of the entries in the bibliography UNALTERED.*

*Note 2: there are related questions out there, but none of them addresses this with \citet{...}*.

Comment: You are using `authoryear-comp`. That style compresses citations such as "Knuth 1984; Knuth 1986" to "Knuth 1984, 1986" to do that, `biblatex` needs to sort the citations (by author and then year) first. If you don't want that, you can disable sorting with `sortcites=false`, which will probably make your style more like `authoryear` in most cases.

Comment: Another simple solution is to use the multicite version `\textcites{hartmascolell}{evans}`, these command are not sorted by default regardless of the `sortcites` setting.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful comments. Would you be so kind to post your comments in an answer for me to accept it and close the question?

Comment: With an up-to-date version of `biblatex` `\DeclareDelimFormat[cbx@textcite]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}` will not be needed any more. You should also add `%` to the line ends in `\AtBeginBibliography` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/35864). `\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-first}` is `\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}` now, but you probably want `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}`. `hyperref=true` is normally useless, the only difference to the default `hyperref=auto` is that the former will issue a warning is the `hyperref` package is not loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing this behaviour because `authoryear-comp` internally sets `sortcites=true`. That option causes citations to be sorted as the works would be cited in the bibliography. This is crucial for the compact/compressed style you use, since all permutations of `\cite{knuth:ct:b,sigfridsson,knuth:ct:a}` should come out as "Knuth 1984, 1986; Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998".

If you don't want any sorting in the citations at all and prefer to determine the sorting manually, you can disable the sorting with `sortcites=false`. This will seriously damage the `-comp` bit of `authoryear-comp`, though. Unless you sort the entries manually, you will more often than not end up with `authoryear` rather than `authoryear-comp`.

Since the multi-cite commands are not sorted by default (see [Sorting citations using \cites command in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65809/35864)), you could use `\textcites` to suppress the sorting

```
\textcites{hartmascolell}{evans}
```

It is possible to sort the citations with a different sorting template than the bibliography, see [Biblatex: how to automatically sort citation by year (sortcites=ynt) when references are sorted by name (sorting=nyt)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/361031/35864).