# Illusion of duplicate causes too many authors to appear after \cite

Tags: biblatex, biber

I have a problem with the way my bibliographic references turn up in the text. I use JabRef to handle the bibliography. In my preamble, I use the option `maxcitenames` and `mincitenames` to make sure that multiple authors (more than 2) will only be cited as "Firstauthor et al." in the document itself, while all the authors are listed in the bibliography. However, I have encountered the following curious problem. Two different papers that I need to quote are both written by four different authors, the first of which is the same in both cases.

Concretely, the author "Wiklund" is the first author of both papers. What I want, is of course the first reference to appear in the text as (Wiklund et al. 2007), and the other as (Wiklund et al. 2009). But somehow, Biber (or perhaps the problem is JabRef) feels it has to cite the second author in both cases to distinguish between the two.

Here is a MWE and below is a picture of what it produces + the JABREF source of the two relevant entries. Notice that if I only reference one of these entries, everything works fine and only (Wiklund et al. 2007) or (Wiklund et al. 2009) appears. The problem is caused by the co-occurrence of these entries.

```
\documentclass[12]{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp, sortcites=false, maxcitenames=2, mincitenames=1, maxbibnames=4]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{flafla.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text\parencite{Wiklundetal2007}. Some more text \parencite{Wiklundetal2009}  

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
@Article{Wiklundetal2009,
  author =  {Wiklund, Anna-Lena and Benzen, Kristine and Hrafnbjargarson, Gunnar Hrafn and Hróarsdóttir, Thorbjörg},
  title =   {On the distribution and illocution of V2 in Scandinavian that-clauses},
  journal = {Lingua},
  year =    {2009},
  volume =  {119},
  number =  {2},
  pages =   {1914-1938}
}

@Article{Wiklundetal2007,
  author =  {Wiklund, Anna-Lena and Hrafnbjargarson, Gunnar Hrafn and Hróarsdóttir, Thorbjörg and Bentzen, Kristine},
  title =   {Rethinking Scandinavian Verb Movement},
  journal = {Journal of Comparative Germanic Linguistics},
  year =    {2007},
  volume =  {10},
  pages =   {203-233}
}
```

Comment: You are probably looking for biblatex's option `uniquelist`. If you set it to `uniquelist=false` does it produce the desired result?

Comment: Btw, please do not post code (the bibentries, in this case) as image. You may edit your question and add them as text, so that people can actually use them without having to type it. (To edit the block as a code block, you can select it and use the `{}` icon).

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864 for a bit of background and explanations. But gusbrs already gave the answer, you probably want `uniquelist=false`.

Comment: BTW: `style=authoryear-comp` with `sortcites=false` may result in some citations not being compressed as normally expected with that style. This may or may not be intended.

Comment: @gusbrs, thanks, that fixed the problem. I used sortcites=false since otherwise, multiple \cites were listed alphabetically rather than chronologically. Now there is no sorting at all, so I just make sure to put them chronologically myself. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, there is no good (safe) way to sort citations and bibliography differently, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/361031/35864. Would you agree that your question is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864?

Comment: @moewe, yes, I agree that this is in fact a duplicate of that question. Btw, I edited my post. Is this the proper way of including JabRef sources and code in general?

Comment: @EspenJK, yes, that's the proper way. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Good, if you agree you may want to consider agreeing to the close-vote cast on your question. (like this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250930) Yes that is how you should include your `.bib` entries. If you want to make it easier for people to help you, you can add them in `filecontents` directly into the `.tex` code (see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864 - but be aware that `filecontents` overwrites files if the `filecontents` package is loaded).