# author citation in chronological order

Tags: biblatex

I use overleaf while I am writing my thesis and I want the authors in each citation to appear in chronological order.

I use biblatex:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=nyt,dashed=false,uniquelist=false,maxnames=1,minnames=1,maxbibnames=99,backend=biber,sortcites=true]{biblatex}
```

An example from my text is the following:

```
these paleolakes could have hosted habitable conditions and contributed organic material to sediments sinks at the landing site. There are many potential fluvial valleys and sediment fans in the study area 
\parencite{molina2017coogoon,fawdon2018ancient,dickeson2020topographic}.
```

but when I recompile it appears like that:

[image: b]

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/361031/35864, please.

Comment: Thank you! I had not noticed that solution!

Comment: I take it the answer worked for you? If that's the case, would you be OK with closing this question as a duplicate?