# Sort citations by year (ynt) and references by name (nyt) in custom biblatex style

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, sorting

I would like to sort my bibliography alphabetically, but a list of citations in-text by year.

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361031/biblatex-how-to-automatically-sort-citation-by-year-sortcites-ynt-when-refere) is about the same problem. However, the answer given relies on wrapping `\printbibliography` in a `refcontext` to change the sorting:

```
\begin{refcontext}[sorting=nyt]
\printbibliography
\end{refcontext}
```

I am writing a custom biblatex style for my university. I would like this behaviour to be the default, without the user of the style needing to change sorting within the document.

What do I need to include in the `.bbx` and/or `.cbx` files to achieve this?

Edit:

I can achieve this using:

```
\NewCommandCopy{\oldprintbibliography}{\printbibliography}
\renewcommand{\printbibliography}{
\begin{refcontext}[sorting=nyt]
  \oldprintbibliography
\end{refcontext}
}
```

But this has the serious drawback that the user is then not able (without errors) to wrap `\printbibliography` in their own `refcontext`.

Comment: Define a user-command in your style that prints both?

Comment: @Cicada Do you mean `\renewcommand{\printbibliography}` ?

Comment: Both ref contexts/commands. In a wrapper. So user types one command.

Comment: @Cicada The standard command to print the bibliography is `\printbibliography`, so I would want that to stay the same and not use some custom `\printourunibib`. So are you suggesting renewing this command? I just assumed there was some way to set the sorting, which is why I asked the question.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\printbibliography}` could be a wrapper, yes. But sorting is attached to styles when not using ref contexts - are you using separate `bibstyle`/`citestyle` options?

Comment: Where is the dividing line between what the user can/cannot adjust going to be? Solution flows from there.

Comment: @Cicada My goal is that the user can adjust anything they want, but that the default sorting is as described without them having to do anything other than setting `style=unistyle`. What do you mean by using separate bibstyle/citestyle? Do you mean like setting `bibstyle=unistyle,citestyle=unistyle`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137131/discussion-between-heisenbugs-and-cicada).

Answer (score 2):

If you use `biblatex` v3.18b (2022-07-12) or above you can use the new `\localrefcontext` and `\GenRefcontextData` to switch to a different reference context (e.g. sorting) in citations as follows

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\AtBeginRefsection{\GenRefcontextData{sorting=ynt}}
\AtEveryCite{\localrefcontext[sorting=ynt]}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,worman,nussbaum,geer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Nussbaum 1978; Geer 1985; Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998; Worman 2002) Geer, Ingrid de (1985). ‘Earl, Saint, Bishop, Skald – and Music. The Orkney Earldom of the Twelfth Century. A Musicological Study’. PhD thesis. Uppsala: Uppsala Universitet. Nussbaum, Martha (1978). Aristotle’s ‘De Motu Animalium’. Princeton: Princeton University Press. Sigfridsson, Emma and Ulf Ryde (1998). ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4, pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P. Worman, Nancy (2002). The Cast of Character. Style in Greek Literature. Austin: University of Texas Press.]

The

```
\AtBeginRefsection{\GenRefcontextData{sorting=ynt}}
```

makes sure that each `refcontext` your document uses also generates one with `ynt` sorting.

The

```
\AtEveryCite{\localrefcontext[sorting=ynt]}
```

switches our citations to the `ynt` sorting `refcontext`. `\localrefcontext` only acts locally and need not be "closed" or reset because it happens inside a group.